# If some preacher utters ill words about some other preacher or saint, can he be treated as Adhikari to preach the Sanatana Dharma?

Tags: scripture, guru, teaching

In Gita, Sri Krishna repeatedly mentions that a spiritual soul should be Advesta, Maitra, Karuna, ie He should be free from bigotry, be friendly to all and be full of compassion. Sri Chaitanyadeva says: Do not criticise other God, other religion (Any deva, anya satra ninda naa koribe).

Ninda or criticism of others has been condemned by all our scriptures and saints.

Can someone who uses ill words against other saints or preachers be considere an Adhikari to preach the Sanatana Dharma according to our scriptures?

Ref: https://vaniquotes.org/wiki/Ramakrishna_mission_(Conversations)

and https://vaniquotes.org/wiki/Vivekananda_(Conversations)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89552/discussion-on-question-by-partha-if-some-preacher-utters-ill-words-about-some-ot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the revered preachers of the Sanatana Dharma are called 'Mahapurusha'-s.

According to the Samudrika-grantha quoted in Sri Chaitanya Charitamrita, the features of a 'Mahapurusha' are

> pancha-dirghah pancha-sukshmah sapta-raktah sad-unnatah/tri-hrasvah prithu-gambhiro dvatrimsal-lakshano mahaan//

In them, three things are gambhira : navi, swara and buddhi.(Mahaprabhu Sri Chaitanya, Radhagovinda Nath, Sadhana Prakashani, page 145).

It is obvious that no one with 'Gambhira-Buddhi' can use ill words against any one.

Gita also says:

> अद्वेष्टा सर्वभूतानां मैत्रः करुण एव च।
>
> निर्ममो निरहङ्कारः समदुःखसुखः क्षमी।।12.13।।
>
> सन्तुष्टः सततं योगी यतात्मा दृढनिश्चयः।
>
> मय्यर्पितमनोबुद्धिर्यो मद्भक्तः स मे प्रियः।।12.14।।
>
> 12.13 He who is not hateful towards any creature, who is friendly and compassionate, who has no idea of 'mine' and the idea of egoism, who is the same under sorrow and happiness, who is forgiving; 12.14 He who is ever content, who is a yogi, who has self-control, who has firm conviction, who has dedicated his mind and intellect to Me-he who is such a devotee of Mine is dear to Me.

None of the great Acharyas attacked any other Acharya personally.They only logically upheld their views against others' doctrine. Use of ill words for personal attacks seem unthinkable for them.

The signs of a 'Sadhu' mentioned in the Mahabharata are

> Na prahrishyati sammaane naavamaane cha kupyati/**na kruddhah parusham bruyat iti etat sadhulakshanam**

meaning a **Sadhu** is never happy by honour and angry by insult.He **never** becomes fury and **utter** **ill** **words**-- these three are signs of a Sadhu (Reference: Omkarnath Rachanavali, vol 1, page 427).

**So I think the answer is a big NO.**